# Exporting a video from Premiere spits out incorrect quality

Tags: premiere, video-quality, encoding, output, bitrate

I'm trying to export a video from Premiere(CC) with the following settings:

[image]

I recorded this video in Motion-JPEG 1080p/60Fps out of Bandicam. I've recorded videos in Bandicam (same settings as mentioned) and edited said videos in Premiere, and exported those videos with the same problem. I only noticed the issue just now.

The only difference in my export settings in Premiere this time, is that I decided to use 60Mbps target, as previous exports have been in the 20-40 range.

When my file had finished rendering I checked the bitrate and file size, and was shocked to discover Windows 7 telling me that it was 12Mbps and 3GB, despite Premiere's target being 60Mbps and estimated 11.5GB.

Looking at my previous video that was 40Mbps Windows is showing an actual bitrate of 8Mbps. My current video took about an hour to render, yet only has a measly 12Mbps.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it/get full quality?

Comment: How is the video *quality*?

Comment: 60 Mb/s is way overkill for 1080p video, even at 60 fps ... note that you set the *target* bitrate, not the average bitrate. Probably Premiere reduced the bitrate because a higher one wouldn't have yielded any better results. Why would you need a bitrate that high anyway?
Also, as @Mulvya mentioned, look at the video and compare the actual video quality ...

Comment: The video does *look* okay, but I'd still prefer maximum quality. I do think that 60Mbps is a bit high, but I don't want anything less than perfect.
Perhaps I should just be exporting in raw lossless format or something.

Comment: If you want lossless, use a lossless code. 'Perfect' does imply that this is what you want - lossy codecs such as H264 are by definition not perfect; they discard information to reduce file size. However, with bitrates that high, the amount of discarded information becomes so small that you won't see much of a difference. So if you can't spot any artifacts (on a good monitor), I would say you have your maximum quality ;-)

Comment: I exported another video with much more motion (video game) and exported at 60Mbps, Premiere spit out 60Mbps. Guess I assumed that targeting 60Mbps wouldn't go as low as 12.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you export with h.264 in Premiere it has two bars as you show. A target bitrate, and a maximum bitrate.

The target bitrate is after all, only a target, and if your video doesn't have enough movement or fast action then you won't get the full Mbps that you've set. Even lowering it enough to only export 12Mbps because your video doesn't have a lot of movement.

Exporting a video with more movement will yield 60Mbps or more, depending on your settings.

Comment: You should not look at target bitrate as one you should hit. You set the quality you want, and it will come out with the bitrate that works for that quality. A lower number than your target is excellent!